# How to add a method into a dict using decorator?

Tags: python, decorator

What I want is something like flask routing register:

```
class ClassName(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.handle_dict = {}

    def handle(data):
        h = self.handle_dict.get(data)
        h()

    @handle_route("open")
    def open_handle()
        """do something"""
        pass

    @handle_route("close")
    def close_handle()
        """do something"""
        pass


    def handle_route()
        """How to implement this warpper?"""
```

I know I could write the a dict in the `__init__` function:

> self.handle_dict = {"open":self.open_handle, "close":self.colse_handle}

But the decorator way looks more clear, right?

I have tried

```
def handle_router(self, path):
    def warpper(f):
        self.handle_map[path] = f
        return f
    return warpper
```

but `self` is not allow in decorator args, `@handle_router(self, "path")` is invalid.

Comment: Given that after five minutes I was not able to find out what exactly you were trying to do with the decorator (or why) I'd say `self.handle_dict = ...` is clearer (or I need my second coffee). :)

Comment: @timgeb, of course, `self.handle_dict` is more transparent and easy to debug, yet decorator way might be easier for developers. Just image that when a developer want a new handler, he just define a new function and add route as a decorator on it instead of move to the head of the class and edit the dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, the handle dict should be some sort of class attribute, as it is filled at class definition time and all instances share the same route-handler mapping. However, the class does not exist yet when the decorator is called and evaluated. You could do something like the following:

```
from functools import partial

class A:
    router = {}

    def handle(self, data):
        m = self.router.get(data)
        return m(self)

    @partial(router.setdefault, 'open')
    def open_handle(self):
        return 5

>>> a = A()
>>> a.handle('open')
5
```

Or be more explicit and extract the routing functionailty to a reuasable class:

```
from functools import partial

class Router(dict):
    __call__ = lambda self, route: partial(self.setdefault, route)

class A:
    router = Router()

    def handle(self, data):
        m = self.router.get(data)
        return m(self)

    @router('open')
    def open_handle(self):
        return 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of decorating the functions, you could just use a consistent naming convention:

```
class ClassName(object):
    def handle(self, type):
        getattr(self, '{}_handle'.format(type))()

    def open_handle(self):
        print('open_handle')

    def close_handle(self):
        print('close_handle')


ClassName().handle('open')

>>> open_handle
```